# How can I format a string with moment js to suppress minutes if the time ends with ":00"?

Tags: javascript, date, formatting, momentjs

I need to format two moment objects to display a time range to users, eg:

> 6:45PM-9:30PM

I know I can get this with

```
`${time1.format('h:mmA')}-${time2.format('h:mmA')}`
```

but I want to suppress minutes when either the start or end time is on the hour, eg:

> 6:45PM-10PM (instead of 6:45PM-10:00PM)
>
> 7PM-9:30PM  (instead of 7:00PM-9:30PM)
>
> 7PM-10PM    (instead of 7:00PM-10:00PM)

I can check to see if the minutes are 0 before and change my formatting string based on that, but that seems inelegant I'd like to do this only using `.format` if possible. Haven't found anything in the formatting [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) about this.

Answer (score 0):

**.format** does not provide that you want inbuilt. Rather you can use string replace function instead.

```
`${time1.format('h:mmA').replace(":00","")}-${time2.format('h:mmA').replace(":00","")}`
```